# number of all inconstant maps f from A to A

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $ A=\{1, 2, 3,..., n\}$. Find the number of all nonconstant maps $f: A \rightarrow A$  for which $f(k) \le f(k + 1)$ and $f(k) = f(f(k + 1))$ for $k = 1, \dots, n-1$..

Comment: Is there something missing?  For $k=n$, the condition says $f(n)\le f(n+1)$, which is impossible since $n+1\notin A$.

Comment: no, its the way it is posted from our professor :S

Comment: @ user78987: Check the way I just rewrote it.

Comment: @HansEngler, that's the natural interpretation, but I didn't want to assume and solve the wrong problem.

Comment: What is the answer for $n = 2$? How about $n = 3$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f(k+1)>k$ for some $k$, then $f(k)\le f(k+1)\le \cdots\le f(f(k+1))$, but since the last term equals the first all inequalities are equalities, so $f(k)=f(k+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a simple case to see what is going on.  If $n=2$, so that $A = \{1,2\}$, then there are only two non-constant maps:

- $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 1$
- $g(1) = 1, g(2) = 2$

but the first can't work because it breaks the rule $f(k) \leq f(k+1)$.  As for $g$, we see that $g(1) = 1$, but $g(g(2)) = g(2) = 2$, so it breaks the second rule.

So there are no maps that satisfy the needed conditions for $n=2$.  For $n=3$, there are more maps, but if you not sure what is happening it's good to work these things out to get an idea.

Hint:  draw two columns for A, like this

$1 \qquad 1$

$2 \qquad 2$

$3 \qquad 3$

and indicate the map by drawing arrows from the left column to the right.  Can you describe a rule for the arrows to match the first condition ($f(k) \leq f(k+1))?  What about the second condition?